# Checking a combination (of a list) while creating it in Prolog

Tags: prolog

In our homework we are given a number of people and who knows who in the form of a database,
like this:

```
person(person1).
person(person2).
person(person3).
person(person4).
person(person5).

knows(person1,person2).
knows(person1,person3).
knows(person2,person4).
knows(person3,person5).
```

The database can contain any number of people with any set of connections.

We have a predicate (findall) that generate a list of the people one person (X) knows:

i.e.

```
findall(Y, knows(Y, person1);knows(person1, Y), AllPeople).
    Y = [person2, person3] .
```

Then have a predicate that generate a combination of these people.

```
comb2(_,[]).
comb2([X|T],[X|Comb]):-comb2(T,Comb).
comb2([_|T],[X|Comb]):-comb2(T,[X|Comb]).
```

Disclaimer: we got this code snippet from:
http://ktiml.mff.cuni.cz/~bartak/prolog/combinatorics.html

i.e.

```
comb2([person2, person3], X).
    X = [] ;
    X = [person2] ;
    X = [person2, person3] ;
    X = [person3] ;
    false.
```

The problem is that our code does a check on every combination (to see that no one in the group know anyone else in the group), and some of the test-cases have people with up to 30 friends (meaning astronomical amounts of combinations).

What we need is some way to test if anyone in the combination we are building know anyone else in the combination, while we are building it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've correctly understood what you meant, an answer is to use `findall/3` again with `AllPeople` to do just that.

```
% Assume that your code is here..

knows(person2,person3).
knows(person3,person2).

group(G) :-
  G = [_,_|_],
  forall(
    ( member(A, G)
    , member(B, G)
    , A \== B), knows(A, B)).
```

Corresponding query is:

```
?- One = person1, 
  findall(E
    , knows(E, One)
    ; knows(One, E), AllPeople),
  findall(G, (comb2(AllPeople, G), group(G)), Groups).

  // ==> Groups = [[person2,person3]]
```